# SQL query to find users that don't have any subscription to a specified list (many-to-many)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, one-to-many

Having two tables, "users" and "lists", and a many-to-many "subscriptions" table relating users to lists (thus having foreign keys `user_id` and `list_id`), what would be a single SQL query to find all the users that don't have any subscription with a specific `list_id` (naturally including the users that have no subscriptions at all)?

Comment: I deleted my answer, so this question should reappear in the unanswered list. Hopefully someone with a better understanding of your problem will give you a better answer.

Comment: You should be clear about your requirement that you don't want to see a user if it has **any** task with `completed = 1`.

Comment: @Welbog: Thanks a lot, I reformulated the problem so that the example makes more practical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time to break out `not exists` again:

```
select
  u.user_id
from
  users u
where
  not exists (
    select 1 from subscriptions s where s.user_id = u.user_id and s.list_id = N
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `NOT IN` and it works well:

```sql
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   "users"
WHERE  "users"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "users"."id"
                            FROM   "users"
                                   INNER JOIN "unsubscribes"
                                           ON "unsubscribes"."user_id" =
                                              "users"."id"
                            WHERE  "unsubscribes"."list" = $1)
```

Ruby on Rails scopes as a bonus:

```rb
  scope :unsubscribed, -> (list) { joins(:unsubscribes).where(unsubscribes: { list: list }) }
  scope :subscribed, -> (list) { where.not(id: User.unsubscribed(list)) }
```